# Android Progress Bar not appearing

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have tried to implement an Async Task by following the advice on an older question on here in order to display my progress bar whilst a method is running (the method takes around 5 seconds to complete)

Here is the implementation of the Async Task:

```
public void runTask() {

        new YourAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            tableStatus();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

The table status method is:

```
public void tableStatus(){

        String tables[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};
        for(int i=0; i<tables.length; i++){
            availableTables(tables[i]);
        }

    }
```

And the availableTables method is a StringRequest method.

Does anyone have any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Well `StringRequest` of Volley are already made for asynchronous execution you do not have to call it from `AsyncTask. What happning is `doInBackground` return immediately after loop  .And why are making request in loop find some other way if this is your requirement . Modify the API maybe.

Comment: Volley and Async together are useless. With volley itself you can make network calls then why Async. And, BTW, The above implementation is also not right.

Comment: Show your layout.xml code.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine for me, but obviously there is something wrong if is not working.

The code I have working and maybe can help you, is a ProgressBar and a TextView inside a LinearLayout, so first I get the LinearLayout:

```
LinearLayout progressBarLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBarLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And then adapting it to your code, should be something like that:

```
public void runTask() {

        new YourAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            tableStatus();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            progressBarLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBarLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

I hope this works for you as well.